# Re-sampling audio alters the speed

Tags: android, audio, mixing

I need to mix audio files with different sample rates. I'm trying to change the sample rate of all the audio files to say 44100Hz. But when I re-sample the audio files, the speed of the original audio is altered (becomes slow). Is there a way to re-sample the audio without altering the speed? I'm using the following function to re-sample the audio file.

http://code.google.com/p/musicg/source/browse/src/com/musicg/dsp/Resampler.java

Answer (score 1):

When you play the resampled audio you should play it with the new sample rate. You may be using the resampled audio at a faster sample rate.

Comment: I'm adding the headers (i.e. wav header) with the new sample rate so I think the media players should be picking up the sample rate from the headers? right?